# Как создать загрузочный экран перед показом формы?

Tags: c#, winforms

У меня есть форма ( **ScreenSplash.cs** ) которая показывает при запуске текст и проверяет некое `bool` значение.

Есть вторая форма (**winforms.cs**) которую нужно показать если ScreenSplash дал результат `bool == true`

---

Так же имеется вот такой вот класс может его можно как-то реализовать в моём вопросе?

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            using (var splash = new Splash<Form2>())
            {
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
            }
        }
    }

    class Splash<T> : IDisposable where T : Form, new()
    {
        private Form mForm;
        private Thread mThread;

        public Splash()
        {
            this.mForm = new T();
            this.mThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.Func));
            this.mThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            this.mThread.Start();
        }

        private void Func()
        {
            Application.Run(this.mForm);
        }

        private delegate void CloseDelegate();

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (this.mForm.InvokeRequired)
            {
                CloseDelegate d = this.mForm.Close;
                this.mForm.Invoke(d);
            }
            else
            {
                this.mForm.Close();
            }

            this.mForm.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

---

Реализовал пока что таким способом:

```
public partial class SplashFrm : Form
{
    Timer timer1 = new Timer();

    public SplashFrm() => this.InitializeComponent();

    private void SplashFrm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.timer1.Interval = 3000;
        this.timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(this.Inizialize);
        this.timer1.Start();
    }

    private void Inizialize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool testing = false;
        if (testing == true)
        {
            this.timer1.Stop();
            if (!this.timer1.Enabled)
            {
                var frm = new WinForm();
                frm.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this.timer1.Stop();
            MessageBox.Show("Форма не равна true");
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: В чем замысел `bool` значения от `ScreenSplash`?

Comment: @Viewed, Ну в `ScreenSplash'e` я хочу проверить какие-то данные, и если они верны ( то есть `bool` равняется `true` ) то показать главную форму.

Comment: Зачем в загрузочном экране проверять что-то? Это ведь просто заглушка для пользователя. Чтобы показать ему "что-то происходит, жди". Запустите эту "заглушку" отдельным потоком и делайте проверку вне нее.

Comment: @Viewed, А можно подробнее? Желательно с примером, если честно я немного не понял о чём вы пишете))

Comment: Эта загрузка будет происходить при запуске приложения?

Comment: @Viewed, Вы имеете в виду проверку? Да при запуске приложения делается проверка

Answer (score 1):

Покажу на примере точки входа `Main()`, файл `Program.cs`. В качестве дополнения посмотрите туториалы по созданию загрузочного экрана. Например, [такое](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wZ4BkPyZllY) или [такое](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KNaC1qghYbc).

```
static class Program
{
    static Thread threadShowSplashScreen;

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        // Создайте поток (будет показывать форму загрузки)
        Thread threadShowSplashScreen = new Thread(ShowSplashScreen)
        {
            Name = "SplashScreen",
            Priority = ThreadPriority.Lowest,
            IsBackground = true
        };

        // Запустите поток
        threadShowSplashScreen.Start();

        // Делайте что-то (форма загрузки уже отображается)
        MainForm mainForm = new MainForm();
        MainPresenter presenter = new MainPresenter(mainForm);

        // Закройте поток (закрыть форму загрузки)
        threadShowSplashScreen.Abort();

        // Запустите основную форму
        // или что вам нужно по условию
        Application.Run(mainForm);
    }

    static void ShowSplashScreen()
    {
        using(SplashScreen ss = new SplashScreen())
        {
            ss.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А как мне передавать информацию в сам `SplashScreen`? И да по поводу это не тот самый `SplashScreen` это уже моя созданная форма просто убрал из неё всё,  накидал туда картинку,  pictureBox, label, выставил всё по уровням))  Сделал форму `FormBorderStyle = None`. А тут как?))

Comment: @Luser `SplashScreen` из примера это ваша уже созданная форма. Передать что-то можно в конструктор формы. Если вы имеете ввиду передавать уже во время того как форма отображается, я не могу помочь. Копайте в сторону обмена данными между потоками.